# How can I get elements from the ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have

```
private List<Test> tests   = new ArrayList<Test>();
```

and

```
void creatingList ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (array[k] == 1)
            {
                Test te = new Test(i, j);
                tests.add(te);
            }
            k++;
        }
}
```

For example, I have here list of numbers or Strings: (1,0); (1,1); (3,5); (5,5)

How can I get elements at specified position in the List? For example, I need second value from the element included in the 3rd parenthesis.

Comment: what do you mean by position of number on line 3 ? Can you elaborate further.

Comment: Please improve your post. I don't know what do you want to achieve,

Comment: Sorry, formating changed it. I meant third 
parenthesis and second number.

Comment: @Revolt You should improve your post. I can only guess that you are asking for `tests.get(2).nameOfTheFieldWhereTheSecondValueIsStored`.
You may have to post part of your `Test` class.

Comment: @Revolt Maybe you are asking for `tests.indexOf(new Test(a,b))` ?

Comment: @Yoda. Yes, this is what I mean. Thank you very much for help

Comment: @Revolt Great, If you want you may accept my answer below. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get element at specified index in the `List` one shoud use `get(int index)` method.

In your case you may want to use:
`tests.get(2).nameOfTheFieldWhereTheSecondValueIsStored.`

It is strongly recommended, to have a glance at documentation before asking a question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Thank you for answer, I know about List. I just didn't know about that: ".nameOfTheFieldWhereTheSecondValueIsStored"